# Does the Standard require explicit casting to void * argument when calling a function?

Tags: c, function, pointers

Consider the following function declaration:

```
void foo(void *);
```

The Standard has explicit paragraph regarding the function call `6.5.2.2/p7`:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
> does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as
> if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking
> the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its
> declared type.

So the argument conversion is performed as if by simple assignment. Now consider the rules of simple assignment `6.5.16.1/p1`:

> the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type,
> and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue
> conversion) one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other
> is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, and the
> type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed
> to by the right;

So conversion to any pointer type from `void *` (**but not vice versa**) is guaranteed by the rule of assignment operator. Now since `6.3.2.3/p1` guarantees legitimacy of conversion to `void *`:

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object
> type.

In order to call a function explicit `(void *)` is required. Example:

```
struct some_struct *ptr = //...
foo(ptr) // non conforming
foo((void *) ptr) //conforming
```

**QUESTION:** Is explicit conversion to `void *` required when calling a function as in the example above to be conforming or I missed something?

Comment: You seem to have missed the significance of the words "**one**" and "**the other**", which is to say that your claim "**(but not vice versa)**" is false.

Comment: As long as neither of the types is a pointer to function (but one is a pointer to object and the other is a void pointer), there is an implicit conversion to or from `void *`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It seems that explicit conversion is required only if the left side is lesser qualified than the right side. For example, `free`ing pointer to a volatile type like `volatile int *`.

Comment: @St.Antario: Well, if you mess with `volatile`, the results are volatile.  You can't free a `const Anything *` either.  So my comment applies to unqualified pointers — you have to deal with qualifiers explicitly (though adding `const` — for example, calling a function with a `const void *` parameter and passing a non-const pointer to some object — does not require a cast; OTOH, removing `const` or `volatile` does require a cast).

Comment: ` Now since 6.3.2.3/p1 guarantees legitimacy of conversion to void *:` and ***from*** too.

Comment: I really don't see your issue, here. The first citation you give says that the first call (which you have marked as non-conforming) implicitly performs the `void* vptr = ptr` assignment and then calls the function with the 'temporary' `vptr`. And your second citation says - quite clearly - that such an assignment is valid: *one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void*

Comment: ... and there are likely gazillions of code bases around that use (for example) `memcpy` and `realloc` calls without explicit casts on the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You missed something - even though you quoted it.

Consider this slightly modified version of the code in the question:

```
void foo(void *p);

struct some_struct *ptr;
foo(ptr);
```

When we call `foo`, we assign its argument `p` as if by

```
void *p = ptr;
```

This is perfectly valid, since

1. *the left operand has ... unqualified pointer type*, and
2. *one operand* (i.e. `ptr`) *is a pointer to an object type*, and
3. *the other* operand (`p`) *is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of `void`*, and
4. *the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right* (i.e. no qualifiers on either side).